# Entity Framework new dbContext in DAL method without using() scope

Tags: c#, entity-framework, static-methods, dbcontext, using-statement

I'm a little bit familiar with Entity Framework for some simple projects, but now I want to go deeper and write better code.

There is plenty of topics talking about whether using statics methods in DAL or not. For the moment I'm more of the side of people who think yes we can use statics methods.

But I'm still thinking if some practices are good or not.

Lot of people do like this:

```
    public IList<Person> GetAll()
    {
        using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
        {
            return dbContext.Persons.ToList();
        }
    }
```

But I'm wondering if doing like this is a good practice:

```
    public static IQueryable<Person> GetAll()
    {
        var dbContext = new MyDbContext();
        return dbContext.Persons;
    }
```

The goal is to use only static methods in a static class as I think it's legit because this class is just a DAL, there will never be any property. I also need to do like this instead of using the using() scope to avoid disposing the context as this method return an IQueryable.

I'm sure some people already think "OMG no, your context will never be disposed", so please read this article: http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html

I tried by myself and yes the context is disposed only when I don't need it anymore.
I repeat, the goal here is to use static methods so I can't use a dbContext property which the constructor instantiate.

So why people always use the using() scope?

Is it a bad practice to do it like I would like to?

Another bonus question: where is the [NotMapped] attribute with EF6? I've checked on both System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations and System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema but can't find it, this attribute is not recognized by the compiler.

Thank's for your answers

Comment: I don't know why, stackoverflow doesn't let me write "Hello all" at the beginning of my topic, don't think I'm impolite :-)

Comment: Adding a `using()` statement effectively disables lazy loading, which may be a good thing...

Comment: Are you planning to always instantiate new dbcontext for each `GetAll` ? It's not just about connection, but also the `Local` cache, if you have plenty of dbcontext alive, the cache will consume a lot of resource

Comment: @DavidG I did't know this thank's for the tips. But anyway, I always prefer to disable it by default in the context's constructor this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

Comment: @YuliamChandra If I understand the article I gave, there is no need to care about it because all the dbcontexts will be disposed automatically when not used anymore. Did I misunderstood something?

Comment: when there is an object in the local cache that is bound to a control, disposal will not happen

Comment: @YuliamChandra do you have a link which explain this please? when I add a "watch" while debugging, it seems that the dbContext is destroyed by the garbage collector. It tells me "The name 'dbContext' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc853327%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) _In most cases, you should create an ObjectContext instance within a using statement (Using…End Using in Visual Basic). This can increase performance by ensuring that the resources associated with the object context are disposed automatically when the code exits the statement block. However, when controls are bound to objects managed by the object context, the ObjectContext instance should be maintained as long as the binding is needed and disposed of manually._

Comment: Ok thank's but if I follow this good practice, it makes impossible to return an IQueryable...

Comment: @Koenigs Why do you want to return `IQuerable<T>`?  It is only worth returning that if you are going to do further expressions against it to refine the generated SQL.  Otherwise, a List implements the `IEnumerable<T>` interface which LINQ also works against.

Comment: I don't understand the obsession with static methods. Why do you have to have static methods?  For Performance? Just what percentage of the processing time do you think you're saving by making your methods static?  You have DB calls which take 10-200ms and a virtual method takes how long to execute?  You're losing all the benefits of OOP and for what?  Have we really come all this way just so we can code like we're implementing in C ?

Comment: It's not a question of performance, the DAL is just a set of methods that provides you a way to access your DB. Some people prefer to store a unique dbContext as a private property and some think it's better to use the using() statement every time. But expect this optional property, you don't need any other one, and there is clearly a problem if you need others. That's why in my point of view instantiate your DAL class doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Given the choice of using objects and not using objects I use objects almost every time because I'm an Object-Oriented Programmer and Designer.  I implement the repository pattern using SOLID http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design) which can't be done with static classes and static methods.  I'd have serious concerns about any substantive business logic that was defined within static classes and methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the [**Repository**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) pattern, **`IQueryable<T>`** shall never be returned anyway.

[**Repository pattern, done right**](http://blog.gauffin.org/2013/01/repository-pattern-done-right/)

Besides, your repositories depend on your [**DbContext**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx). Let's say you have to work on customers in an accounting system.

**Customer**

```
public class Customer {
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    public string GivenName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

**CustomerRepository**

```
public class CustomerRepository {
    public CustomerRepository(DbContext context) { 
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        this.context = context; 
    }

    public IList<Customer> GetAll() { return context.Customers.ToList(); }
    public IList<Invoice> GetInvoicesFor(Customer customer) {
        return context.Invoices
            .Where(invoice => invoice.Customer.Id == customer.Id)
            .ToList();
    }

    private readonly DbContext context;
}
```

So in fact, to answer your question in a more concise and precise way, I think neither approach is good. I would more preferably use a **DbContext** per business concern. When you access let's say the **Customers Management** features, then instantiate a single **DbContext** that shall be shared across all of your required repositories, then dispose this very **DbContext** once you exit this set of features. This way, you shall not have to use **Using** statements, and your contexts should be managed adequately.

Here's another short and simple good reference for the **Repository** pattern:

[**Repository (Martin Fowler)**](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)

**In response to comments from the OP**

> **But actually the point is I don't want to follow the repository pattern. People say "what about if your data source change?" I want to answer, what about if it never change? What the point of having a such powerful class but not using it just in case one day the database provider may change**

Actually, the **Repository Pattern** doesn't only serve the purpose of easier data source change, it also encourages better separation of concerns and a more functional approach closer to the business domain as members in the repository shall all revolve around business terminologies.

For sure the repository itself cannot take over control to dispose a data context or whatever the object it uses to access the underlying data source, since it doesn't belong to it, it is only lended to it so that it can fulfill its tasks.

As for your point about will the data source change someday? No one can predict it. It is most likely to never change in most of the systems I have worked on. A database change is more likely to be seen after 10 years of the initial development for moerdnization purposes. That day, however, you'll understand how the **Repository Pattern** saves you time and headaches in comparison to a tightly coupled code. I work with tightly coupled code from legacy systems, and I do take the advantages for benefits. Prevention is better than cure.

> **But please lets focus on instantiate the dbContext in methods without the using() statement. Is it really bad? I mean also when we inject the context in the constructor we don't handle the dispose(), we let entity framework doing it and it manages it pretty well.**

No, it isn't necessarily bad not to use **using** statements, as long as you dispose all unnecessary resources as long as they are no longer used. The **using** statements serves this purpose for you by doing it automatically instead of you having to take care about.

As for the **Repository** pattern, it can't dispose the context that is passed to it, and it shan't be disposed neither because the context is actually contextualized to a certain matter and is used across other features within a given business context.

Let's say you have Customer management features. Within them, you might also require to have the invoices for this customer, along with the transaction history. A single data context shall be used across all of the data access as long as the user works within the customer management business context. You shall then have one `DbContext` injected in your Customer management feature. This very same `DbContext` shall be shared across all of the repositories used to access your data source.

Once the user exits the Customer management functionalities, the `DbContext` shall get disposed accordingly as it may cause memory leaks. It is false to believe that as long as it is no longer used, everything gets garbage collected. You never know how the .NET Framework manages its resources and how long it shall take to dispose your `DbContext`. You only know that it might get disposed somehow, someday.

If the `DbContext` gets disposed immediately after a data access is performed, you'll have to instantiate a new instance everytime you need to access the underlying data source. It's a matter of common sense. You have to define the context under which the `DbContext` shall be used, and make it shared across the identified resources, and dispose it as soon as it is no longer needed. Otherwise, it could cause memory leaks and other such problems.

**In response to comment by Mick**

> **I would go further and suggest you should always return IQueryable to enable you to reuse that result passing it into other calls on your repositories. Sorry but your argument makes absolutely no sense to me. Repositories are not meant to be stand-alone one stop shops they should be used to break up logic into small, understandable, encapsulated, easily maintained chunks.**

I shall disagree to always return `IQueryable<T>` through a `Repository`, otherwise what is it good to have multiple methods for? To retrieve the data within your repository, one could simply do:

```
public class Repository<T> where T : class {
    public Repository(DbContext dataContext) { context = dataContext; }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll() { return context.Set<T>(); }

    private readonly DbContext context;
}
```

and place predicates everywhere in your code to filter the data as per the views needs or whatsoever. When it is time to change the filter criterion or the like, you'll have to browse all of your code to make sure anyone didn't use a filter which was actually unexpected, and may cause the system to misbehave.

On a side note, I do understand your point and I might admit that for some reasons as described in your comment, it might be useful to return `IQueryable<T>`. Besides, I simply wonder for what good is it, since a repository's responsibility is to provide a class everything it needs to get its information data. So if one needs to pass along `IQueryable<T>`s to another repository, it sounds strange to me as if one wouldn't have completely investigated every possible way to retrieve data. If one need some data to process another query, lazy-loading can do it and no need to return `IQueryable`s. As per its name, `IQueryable`s are made to perform queries, and the `Repository`'s responsibility to to access the data, that is, to perform queries.

Comment: But actually the point is I don't want to follow the repository pattern. People say "what about if your data source change?" I want to answer, what about if it never change? What the point of having a such powerful class but not using it just in case one day the database provider may change...

Comment: But please lets focus on instantiate the dbContext in methods without the using() statement. Is it really bad? I mean also when we inject the context in the constructor we don't handle the dispose(), we let entity framework doing it and it manages it pretty well.

Comment: Returning IQueryable and implementing the repository pattern are not mutually exclusive.  If somehow returning IEnumerable gives you better design than returning IQueryable (which inherits IEnumerable) I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what good design is

Comment: @Mick: Then again, it depends. I agree that `IQueryable<T>` and repositories are not necessarily mutually exclusive. Besides, a well defined business requirement in terms of search capabilities shall not require an `IQueryable` as a result as no further filtering shall be required. Aside, if it is, it is still possible to filter over a list. Still, lists are best to be returned, depending on how well are defined business requirements. The base repository, however, might as well return an `IQueryable` for better extensibility.

Comment: I use IQueryable all the time.  E.g. I ask for an IQueryable of locations from a Location Repository specifying a criteria. I then pass that IQueryable to an EmployeeRepository asking for a list of Employees at those Locations.  Why IQueryable?  Because I can use it to get a list of locations plus I can pass it to the Employee Repository which can incorporate the business logic from the LocationRepository to create a single SQL query to return me the Employees.  Seems pretty sound and reasonable no?

Comment: I would go further and suggest you should always return IQueryable to enable you to reuse that result passing it into other calls on your repositories.  Sorry but your argument makes absolutely no sense to me.  Repositories are not meant to be stand-alone one stop shops they should be used to break up logic into small, understandable, encapsulated, easily maintained chunks.

Comment: In the end, there are many ways of doing the same things. Take 20 programmers/architects and you'll probably have nearly 20 ways of doing the same. I based my answer on JGauffin's blog post who has probably better expressed his arguments. The repository shall express functional business requirements in regards to data access. If you need to pass from one repository to another using `IQueryable`s, perhaps are there some flaws in the way business requirements are fulfilled, and perhaps not, it all depends on the way the surrounding architecture is set in place.